# Laravel package musonza/groups Laravel 5 user groups package how to start after running migrations?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have been able to finish up but the migrations part but i don't know how to start I'm new to laravel and i want to use this package in a project i'm building. Any tutorials, guidance or recommendations is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you run your migrations in the console? `php artisan migrate`

Comment: yes i did that. how to proceed further is what i'm finding very difficult?